# Finding and ploting the maxima and minima points of an numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, max, signals, maximize

I'm trying to find and plot the exact number and locations of peaks in an numpy array.

I've tried using the argrelextrema function but it's not finding the right points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
%matplotlib inline

ID = 64008
array = frame[frame["IdVeiculo"] == ID]["Laco_1_Amplitude"].to_numpy()

plt.plot(array)

maxima = argrelextrema(array, np.greater, mode="wrap")
peak_indexes = maxima[0]

peak_x = peak_indexes
peak_y = array[peak_indexes]
plt.plot(peak_x, peak_y, marker='o', linestyle='dashed', color='red', label="Peaks")
```

In this case it's supposed to be 7 peaks:
[Wrong Peaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhZbf.png)

And this one only 1 peak
[Wrong Peak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFHXu.png)

My array for the first example is:

```
array([ 50,  55,  59,  66,  71,  78,  87,  94, 103, 115, 126, 138, 152,
   165, 177, 191, 202, 216, 228, 239, 246, 255, 262, 269, 274, 276,
   278, 283, 281, 283, 281, 278, 276, 274, 274, 269, 267, 262, 258,
   258, 253, 253, 248, 246, 246, 244, 241, 241, 239, 239, 237, 234,
   234, 234, 232, 232, 232, 230, 228, 228, 225, 225, 223, 223, 223,
   223, 218, 225, 225, 228, 230, 232, 232, 237, 239, 244, 246, 248,
   251, 253, 255, 258, 260, 260, 264, 269, 274, 278, 287, 297, 306,
   320, 331, 345, 359, 370, 387, 403, 426, 437, 446, 449, 446, 469,
   465, 469, 474, 469, 458, 442, 426, 410, 393, 377, 361, 343, 331,
   317, 304, 292, 285, 276, 274, 264, 262, 258, 253, 248, 246, 244,
   241, 239, 239, 237, 237, 234, 234, 232, 234, 234, 234, 234, 237,
   237, 239, 241, 244, 248, 251, 253, 255, 260, 264, 267, 271, 274,
   278, 285, 287, 290, 292, 294, 297, 297, 297, 292, 292, 287, 283,
   278, 274, 264, 258, 251, 246, 244, 241, 239, 237, 239, 244, 248,
   255, 262, 271, 283, 292, 306, 317, 329, 340, 352, 364, 373, 380,
   389, 393, 396, 403, 405, 407, 410, 410, 412, 412, 412, 414, 412,
   412, 412, 405, 400, 396, 389, 380, 370, 361, 350, 336, 324, 313,
   304, 294, 287, 281, 274, 271, 271, 271, 274, 276, 281, 287, 297,
   306, 315, 322, 331, 343, 347, 357, 361, 366, 368, 373, 373, 375,
   375, 375, 375, 375, 373, 373, 373, 368, 370, 368, 366, 366, 361,
   359, 359, 354, 352, 350, 345, 343, 340, 336, 336, 331, 327, 322,
   322, 322, 317, 311, 308, 308, 306, 306, 306, 306, 304, 304, 313,
   306, 306, 306, 329, 320, 315, 361, 419, 453, 343, 345, 357, 368,
   380, 393, 405, 419, 423, 428, 444, 463, 467, 474, 472, 481, 488,
   490, 495, 497, 499, 499, 499, 499, 497, 495, 493, 488, 481, 472,
   463, 453, 442, 430, 419, 405, 393, 384, 373, 361, 357, 350, 345,
   340, 338, 338, 340, 343, 350, 359, 366, 375, 387, 396, 410, 421,
   433, 446, 456, 467, 479, 488, 499, 506, 513, 518, 525, 525, 527,
   529, 527, 525, 522, 520, 516, 511, 506, 504, 497, 493, 486, 481,
   474, 469, 467, 463, 458, 456, 453, 453, 449, 446, 446, 444, 444,
   440, 440, 437, 430, 430, 423, 416, 410, 403, 391, 380, 366, 352,
   338, 320, 304, 287, 269, 253, 234, 214, 198, 182, 168, 156, 140,
   129, 117, 105,  96,  87,  78,  71,  69,  62,  57,  52,  50,  43,
    43,  36,  36,  34,  29,  27,  23,  20,  18,  18,  13,  13,  13,
    11,  11,   6,   6,   6,   4,   4,   6,   4,   0,   0,   0,   0,
     2,   0,   0,   2,  -2,  -2,   0,  -2,  -2,  -2,  -4,  -4,  -4,
    -2,  -2,  -2,  -6,  -6,  -4,  -6,  -4,  -4,  -6,  -6,  -4,  -6,
    -6,  -6,  -6,  -4,  -6,  -4,  -4,  -6,  -4,  -6,  -6,  -6,  -9,
    -6,  -6,  -4,  -6,  -4,  -4,  -4,  -4,  -6,  -4,  -4,  -4,  -4,
    -4,  -4,  -2,  -2,   0,  -2,  -2,  -2,   0,  -2,   0,  -4,   0,
    -2,  -2,  -4,  -2,  -2,  -4,  -4,  -2,  -2,  -2,  -2,   0,  -2,
    -2,   0,  -2,   0,   0,  -2,  -4,  -4,  -2,  -2,  -2,  -2,  -2,
    -2,   0,  -2,  -2,   0,  -4,  -2,   0,  -4,  -2,   0,  -2])
```